# Refer a property of another bean in Spring 2.5.X

Tags: spring, spring-2.5

In Spring 3.0 and higher it is possible to refer a property of another bean as below.

```
<bean id="a" class="A">
    <property name="list"
        value="#{b.list}"/>
</bean>
```

Is there a way I can refer property of another bean in Spring 2.5.1. 
    Note that Spring Expression integrated after Spring 3.0

Answer (score 0):

Spring is a framework for dependency injection and not for value injection. If your bean a has dependency on bean b for its creation, then why not inject the bean b in bean a.

Spring do give limited feature for injecting values but that is only for configuring the components i.e. beans.

Comment: There are instances where you cannot create bean B in Bean A but need to refer value. For example I need to inject a value to publishedEndpointUrl in below Entry in Applicationcontext. I cannot declare any bean inside in JAXWS endpoint. <jaxws:endpoint id="serviceEndpoint"
  implementor="#webService" address="/public/api/ws-service/v1" publishedEndpointUrl="#bean.property"/> . I can do this with Spring version 3 and above with Spring Expression language. How to make this in Spring 2.5 is the question at hand ?